# How to format multiple lines of code on a single line with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Previously it was possible to format several lines of code in a single line with `ctrl + j`. I would like to know how I can edit the `keybinding.json` file in order to achieve this.

Comment: Are you referring to the "Format Selection" command? If so, on my VS it is available as Ctrl-K, Ctrl-F and is available in the Edit menu.

Comment: In my VS `ctrl-k + ctrl-f` is to close the work area, so I don't know how to format several lines of code on a single line. as for example an object in JavaScript.

Comment: ok, that is just your default key binding which may differ depending on what your environment is set to. What version of Visual Studio are you using? In the Edit menu of VS, look in the "Advanced" Submenu. There should be "Format Selection" which you can select directly from menu but to the right of the menu label should be what its current key binding is too. [sometimes it is set to Ctrl-E, Ctrl-F so try that]